# Check a column to see if there is a named range in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm dealing with over 300 named ranges in a spreadsheet that are each individual cells to identify individual columns.  (They are not the column names, as there are many duplicates)

Question:  If I have a named range that is:

```
myRange = Range(cells(2,7).address)
```

and the active cell is

```
cells(5,7)
```

is there a way to identify the fact that I can identify from the column number in my active cell, that I am in the same column as the named range, and return that named range's name?

Something like.......

```
Function Get_RangeName(MyColumn) as string
   For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
       if ***code to get coloumn number here*** = Mycolumn then
          Get_RangeName = nm.name
       end if
   next nm
end function
```

I just don't know how to get the column number from the name

Comment: Range(nm).Column will return the column number of the range which has the name contained in the string variable nm

Comment: @YowE3K - what if the named range covers more than a single column?

Comment: @Jeeped each one is only one column.  This is for a stopgap measure that will only last a few months during a redesign.  The ranges will never be more than a single cell.

Comment: @Jeeped In this question, each of the named ranges was said to refer to a single cell, so therefore they won't span columns.

Comment: @YowE3K -Yes, you are correct. I suppose my effort toward providing more universality was misguided.

Comment: @Jeeped Definitely not misguided - I upvoted Scott's answer (which is almost identical to yours) as soon as it appeared because, even though it would be slightly more inefficient than just using the Range(nm).Column method I proposed in my comment, it would be a more robust solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Intersect() function

```
Function Get_RangeName(MyColumn as Long) as string
   For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
       if Not Intersect(Columns(Mycolumn),Range(nm)) Is Nothing then
          Get_RangeName = nm.name
          Exit For
       end if
   next nm
end function
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772.aspx) to determine if the two ranges share any cells.

```
if not intersect(columns(cells(5,7).column), range("myNamedRange")) is nothing then
    'the full column and the named range share at least 1 cell
end if
```